# How to stream video to iOS via RTMP?

Tags: ios, url, video, stream, rtmp

I'm new to dealing with web services, as the majority of contract work I normally do is using local files, but my current contract requires streaming a remote video file. When I attempt to get the streaming URL through the REST API I am returned the following JSON payload:

```
{
    "Video": {
        "CdnUrl": {CDNURL},
        "ImageFileName": {IMAGEFILENAME},
        "OtherFileFormat": {FLVVIDEOFILENAME},
        "VideoDescription": {DESCRIPTION},
        "VideoFileName": {MP4FILENAME},
        "VideoId": {INTEGER},
        "VideoTitle": {TITLE}
    }
}
```

I took out all of the values because they shouldn't be relevant. The problem is that I don't know how to access the video files with an RTMP URL. Is this possible on iOS, and if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iOS SDK does not support the RTSP protocol.
This is  custom [RTMP Library for iPhone](http://www.aftek.com/afteklab/aftek-iphone-RTMP-library.shtml)

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to implement that Library!

Comment: i need some help for RTMP.

Answer (score 0):

It may help you
[Brightcove Player iOS SDK](http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/mobile-sdks/brightcove-player-sdk-for-ios/index.html)